# Easiest way to sort Hash of Arrays by [3] numeric value

Tags: perl, sorting

What is the easiest way to sort Hash of Arrays by [3] numeric value?

For example... I want to sort the hash with values 6125, 1686, 700 from largest to smallest value. I originally though about putting those values as keys, but some of those number are the same in other arrays.

```
'12' => [
     '+',
     'ATGGTTTTCTTCTCTCCTTCCCTCTCCAGCCTGCTGTATAAGTAA',
     'MGLGLAPSWPSLLTSSYPECVPYLFSHLLPPTTQPYPFSPSLSSLLYK*',
     6125
     ],
'41' => [
     '+',
     'ATGGGAGTTTACTGTGATGACTTGAGGACAGAGGGACTCTAG',
     'MGVYCDDLRTEGL*',
     1686
     ],
'16' => [
     '+',
     'ATGGGAGTTTACTGTGATGACTTGAGGACAGAGGGACTCTAG',
     'MGVYCDDLRTEGL*',
     700
     ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just sort the keys using a `sort` block

```
my @sorted_keys = sort {  $data{$b}[3] <=> $data{$a}[3] } keys %data;
```